# PHP Array Values Not Leaving foreach Loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am looping through a series of inputs and saving their values to an array. Each element in the array is a special class that has a name (so it can be uniquely identified) and an answer (initialized as null, populated in the following loop):

```
class Question
{
    public name;
    public answer;
}

...

foreach ($quiz_questions as $q)
{
    $inputName = $q->name;
    $response = $_POST[$inputName];
    $q->answer = $response;
    print_r($q->answer);
}
print_r($quiz_questions);
```

When I print each individual answer during the iteration, the values come out correctly, but when I print the entire array after the loop, the answer components are NULL like they were before the loop.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: do u define $quiz_questions?

Comment: `foreach ($quiz_questions as &$q)`

Comment: no,where u define $quiz_questions?same as a $quiz_questions=array(1,2,3)

Answer (score 1):

As you say that each element in the array is a class, use the `get_object_vars()` function to access the class attributes.

```
get_object_vars($quiz_questions));
```

should do the work.